# How to send email to all members of mailing list with Mailgun API

Tags: python, email, mailgun

I do not understand fully the mailgun API logic. 
 Here is my problem

I want to send an email to my mailing list (i.e `mailinglist@mg.mydomain.com`). But if I use the API with the following code:

```
def send_simple_message(subject, message):
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.mydomain.com/messages",
        auth=("api", "****-*****-****"),
        data={"from": "some-user@mg.mydomain.com",
              "to": ["mailinglist@mg.mydomain.com"],
              "subject": subject,
              "text": message})
```

The message is not delivered to all the subscribers of the mailing list. If set a list of all my users in the `"to": ["user1@domain1.com", "user2@domain1.com", "user3@domain2.com"]` they recieve the email but not from the mailing therefore can see each others email adresse.

Comment: The API say ....Email address of the recipient(s). Example: "Bob <bob@host.com>" ...if you put Name before of e-mail?....like "MailingList <mailinglist@mg.mydomain.com>"

Comment: I tried this as well :) It does not work.

Comment: I think the problem is the mail list...I would do a new list test just with 2 email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [GiovaniSalazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10569027/giovanisalazar), the problem was indeed in the mailing list. The code is correct, but you need to add the sender (in my example `some-user@mg.mydomain.com`) the rights to send to the mailing list in the mailgun mailinglist dashboard... Shame on me!

Comment: How did you do to add the rights to the sender in the mailinglist dashboard? I think I'm facing the same problem that you described in your question.